# how to write to an xml file using flex

Tags: actionscript, flex3, flex4

I have an application which takes live data from internet,
  I want to develop another application which reads data from the internet and writes it
  to an XML file (i.e. I want to save the state in an XML file).

THE ONLY THING I NEED IS HOW TO WRITE THIS DATA IN AN XML FILE. I WANT TO SAVE THE XML FILE
ON LOCAL DRIVE (SAY C: DRIVE OR D: DRIVE BUT ON LOCAL HARD DRIVE

FOR EXAMPLE  say I have a combo box which takes top 10 fifa world cup watching sites,
  now I want to write this information (i.e. whatever the data this combo box takes as input
  into an xml file).

I want the answer in flex only. And I don't want answer in AIR.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to save the file - client or server? You can't write at client machine without using AIR - or else you can prompt a download and ask user to manually save it. At server, you can't do it just with Flex - gotta use some server side script like PHP/ASP/JSP etc - what's your server side like?

Answer (score 0):

How about [`FileReference::save`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) ?